# iOS: Fire notification after time period and keep track of time

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I'm writing a game where the user can have N lives, where each life is replenished after a set period of time, T.

What is the best way to implement this in iOS, given that the user may or may not have the app opened when a life replenishes.

I was thinking that I could fire a UILocalNotification, but is it guaranteed that this will always be fired (e.g. what if the phone was turned off)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use a notification for this as it is presented to the user. Instead, while the app is open you should be running a timer and replenishing when it fires. You should also be storing the replenish date, perhaps in user defaults or the keychain, so that if the app is closed you can compare that date to now when it is opened again and determine how many to replenish.